# Moving files from Linux server to Window 2012 Server

Tags: linux

I normally store my Linux system backup files to CD's. I want to move the backup files to a 2012 Windows Server I use for management purposes.  I am limited to Linux CLI and 2012 Server services, no 3rd party software allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your options boil down to 3 basic methods:

1. Sneakernet:  That is, copy your files from the Linux server to a removable medium such as a flash drive or an external hard drive.  It sounds like you already have the files on physical CD.  If the Windows server has an optical drive, just pop the CD's into the drive and copy the files.
2. Mount a Windows share on the Linux server:  For that you'll probably need to install some packages on the Linux server.  The specific packages depend on your distro.
3. Mount an NFS share on your Windows server.  You'll need to install the NFS Client, which is part of Windows Features.

Option 1 involves copying the files twice, but is probably easier overall.

Comment: Could probably also use FTP which I believe is supported by win server 2012 though probably have to install as a windows feature.

Comment: Yes, that would work if the OP wants to install an FTP server on the Windows server.  It comes as part of IIS.

Comment: Thanks fellas, I was leaning more towards a SFTP or SCP option.  However, I have not found any "How to" instructions on how to pull it off.  I keep running into hurdles that side tracks me to point of frustration.

Comment: If you have a Windows 10 computer, you can use either of those.  Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which you can use to connect to your Linux server via SFTP or SCP.  That will get the files onto your Windows 10 box.  After that, you can just use SMB (Windows sharing) to move them onto the Windows server.

Comment: Good Idea Charles, I will look into that. Thanks